# How do I move the last item in a list to the front in python?

Tags: python, list

I searched thoroughly but can't find anything relating to this exact specific. I have a list:

```
a = [two, three, one]
```

I want to move `one` to the front, so it becomes:

```
a = [one, two, three]
```

The thing is, it could be ANY amount of numbers in the list. Assume there is no way of knowing whether there will be 50 items or 3.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Basically:

```
a.insert(0, a.pop())
```

Consider using [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) if you're doing that often, though.

Comment: This is what I was going to say :). You could remove the pop index too.

Comment: @junjanes: It shouldn't work for empty lists. What do you want to move in an empty list?

Comment: @MattJoiner: Slightly misread the question, wasn't sure if OP wants to move always last or any item.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: The OP asks for a solution that works for any number of items.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `deque`. Its `rotate` method is a shortcut for this operation. `a.insert(0, a.pop(-1))` is O(n) for lists, while the equivalent `a.appendleft(a.pop())` or `a.rotate()` is O(1) for deques.

Comment: @junjanes: It works for any positive number on items (well, it's superfluous for one, but still). The operation itself is undefined for an empty list, and IMHO it's better to raise an exception in that case, rather than trying to move something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Plus, if you don't want exceptions, you can always do `if a: a.insert(0, a.pop())`. :P

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus In an automatic treatment , it may be interesting to use the junjanes' one-liner, to obtain a condensed secure code. One could also use a try-except or a pre-execution verification if a. It depends on the need and goal. But he junjanes is right to point this eventuality (by the way its one-liner also works for a list having only one element). The pitfall I see in this one-liner is that it builds a new list while other solutions don't . [This comment of mine gives me the impression to be written in very bad english. Excuse me for that]

Comment: hey guys, will always be something in the list :) thanks so much

Comment: @Jared Then ``a.insert(0, a.pop())`` is better imo, because the modification is in place I think

Comment: @gnibbler It depends on the operations the more often performed on the object. Memory movement costs for pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations are O(1) on a deque and O(n) on a list, but _" list objects (...) are optimized for fast fixed-length operations"_

Comment: @eyquem: There is no way that a.insert(0, whatever) can be done in situ; all the pointers in a[1:] need to be moved up one slot; it's an O(N) operation.

Comment: @eyquem: (1) source of quote please (2) insert(0, v) is a fixed-length operation??

Comment: @John Machin 1) (http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) I mean that if the ``a.insert(0, a.pop())`` operation is performed only one time , while many other fixed-length operations must be done after, it could be interesting to keep ``a`` a list instead of making ``a`` a deque just for the benefit of better cost on the first ``a.insert(0, a.pop())`` operation

Comment: @John Machin 2) I imagine that the poping of last element must be done first (so length diminishes of 1) and the insertion is done after (so length raises of 1), that is to say the two operations are not done together in the same time. But I'm not sure, it's my feeling, and in fact I wonder what is a fixed_length operation

Comment: @John Machin Could you explain more this : _"all the pointers in a[1:] need to be moved up one slot;"_ Where are all these pointers ? where are the said slots ?

Comment: @eyquem: I cannot decode the 1st and 2nd of you most recent 3 comments. Re the 3rd: in CPython, a list is in effect a contiguous array of pointers to objects, with some free space at the end. Each pointer occupies one 4-byte or 8-byte slot. BTW I meant a[0:] not a[1:]; to accomplish insert(0, v) requires moving all the pointers "up" to make space for 1 more pointer.

Comment: @John Machin Thank you for your explanation on question in 3. I will study more thoroughly this subject later, with the help of interesting web pages I found. Concerning my comments 1, I'm surprised that it appears obscure; and comment 2, I won't be annoyed if you forget it.

Answer (score 17):

The `-1` index relates to the last item.

```
a = a[-1:] + a[:-1]
```

This will work for any number of elements in list.

Comment: Sure, it works for every length of ``a``, but if the case 'void a' is possible, I prefer: ``a.insert(0, a.pop()) if a else None`` It seems weird, but it works and the operations are in place

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code:

```
a.insert(0, a.pop())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to move first item of a list to last , you can use this -

```
lst=['one','two','three']
lst.insert(len(lst),lst.pop(0)) # result ['two','three','one']
```

Answer (score 3):

## Fun

### insert

The best way was just indicates as:

```
>>> a = ["two","three","one"]
>>> a.insert(0,a.pop())
>>> a
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

### pop

But, if I should do something original, I will make this:

```
>>> a = ["two","three","one"]
>>> a = [a.pop()] + a
>>> a
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

### slice

And, last exercize, this:

```
>>> a = ["two","three","one"]
>>> a = [a[-1]] + a[:-1]
>>> a
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['two', 'three', 'one']
a = a[-1:] + a[0:-1]
print a



a = ['two', 'three', 'one']

a[0:0] = a[-1:]
del a[-1]
print a
```

I prefer the second manner because the operations are in place, while in the first manner a new list is created

Comment: While  it is "in place" every reference in `a` needs to be moved, so deque is probably better unless `a` is very small

Comment: @gnibbler I am interested by your comment but I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: @eyquem, whether you use insert or slice assignment, The underlying list starts at the same memory location, so putting an extra element in front is equivalent to a[1]=a[0];a[2]=a[1];a[3]=a[2]... This is done at the C level, so is ~100 times faster than the equivalent Python code, but the number of assignments is proportional to the length of the list, so the operation is O(n)

Comment: @gnibbler Thank you. It's a vast subject, I will study it more thoroughly later. I understand that during an in-place operation, the locations of objects do not change, but the values of pointers pointing to this objects change in the underlying C vector of pointers: then the cost of operation is O(n), OK; but I wouldn't call these changings "assignement". An assignement is more than a changing of value, since it implies an object, not a variable as is a pointer.

Comment: @gnibbler By the way, you certainly wanted to write: ....a[4] = a[3] ; a[3] = a[2] ; a[2] = a[1] ; a[1] = a[0] ; a[0] = inserted value.

Comment: @eyquem, heh, yeah best to get the order right. In CPython, it is indeed just a matter of shuffling n pointers, but the operations is still O(n)